# ggplot2 legend not displaying all my breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set plotting plankton abundance across the Southern Ocean.
I have abundance values from 3333.33, all the way to 15000.
For some reason, even with breaks, my plots only show one break in the legend. Regardless if there is data within my set breaks.

This is my code:

```
tsbreaks \<- c(2500, 5000, 15000)

ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill="grey", alpha=0.8) +
geom_point(data=AllOct, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), col="lightgrey") +
geom_point(data=CrioAbunOct, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, col=value, size=value)) +
geom_sf(data=fronts, inherit.aes = FALSE, col="grey") +
scale_color_gradient(low="royalblue2", high="red3", breaks=tsbreaks, labels=tsbreaks) +
guides(colour=guide_legend(), size=guide_legend())+
scale_size_continuous(name="Abundance", breaks=tsbreaks, labels=tsbreaks) +
theme_minimal() +
labs(title = "Chaetoceros criophilus", color = "Abundance", size = "Abundance", subtitle = "October     abundance",
x = "Longitude",
y = "Latitude")+
coord_sf(xlim = c(55,160), ylim = c(-68,-40))
```

the AllOct data frame contains all sampling effort in the Southern Ocean in October
The CrioAbunOct data frame shows only one species (criophilus), derived from AllOct

the column I want to plot is called "value"

This is my current output
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRlYR.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `scale_color_steps(name="Abundance", breaks=tsbreaks, labels=tsbreaks)`. What do you get?